# Recording audio to a file

Tags: c++, winapi, wav

I'm trying to implement the functions of recording sound from the microphone, its output and writing to a file. I use "winmm.lib".The first 2 functions are already there and I can't write the last one. Is it possible to write this function with CreateFileA()?

The functions I have done:

```
const int NUMPTS = 44100 * 2 * 5;   // 5 seconds
int sampleRate = 44100;
short int waveIn[NUMPTS];

void Record(WAVEFORMATEX *MFX)
{
    WAVEFORMATEX pFormat;
    pFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    
    pFormat.nChannels = 2;                   
    
    pFormat.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    pFormat.nSamplesPerSec = sampleRate;
    pFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = sampleRate * pFormat.nChannels * pFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8;
    pFormat.nBlockAlign = pFormat.nChannels * pFormat.wBitsPerSample / 8;
    pFormat.cbSize = 0;

    HWAVEIN hWaveIn;
    WAVEHDR waveInHdr;

    waveInOpen(&hWaveIn, WAVE_MAPPER, &pFormat, 0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

    waveInHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
    waveInHdr.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS * 2;
    waveInHdr.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
    waveInHdr.dwUser = 0L;
    waveInHdr.dwFlags = 0L;
    waveInHdr.dwLoops = 0L;

    waveInPrepareHeader(hWaveIn, &waveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    waveInAddBuffer(hWaveIn, &waveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));
    
    waveInStart(hWaveIn);


    // Wait until finished recording
    do {} while (waveInUnprepareHeader(hWaveIn, &waveInHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR)) == WAVERR_STILLPLAYING);

    waveInClose(hWaveIn);
    (*MFX) = pFormat;
}

void ListenRec(WAVEFORMATEX pFormat)
{
    HWAVEOUT hWaveOut;
    WAVEHDR WaveOutHdr;

    waveOutOpen(&hWaveOut, WAVE_MAPPER, &pFormat, 0L, 0L, WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT);

    WaveOutHdr.lpData = (LPSTR)waveIn;
    WaveOutHdr.dwBufferLength = NUMPTS * 2;
    WaveOutHdr.dwBytesRecorded = 0;
    WaveOutHdr.dwUser = 0L;
    WaveOutHdr.dwFlags = 0L;
    WaveOutHdr.dwLoops = 1L;

    waveOutPrepareHeader(hWaveOut, &WaveOutHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    waveOutSetVolume(hWaveOut, 0xFFFFFFFF);

    waveOutWrite(hWaveOut, &WaveOutHdr, sizeof(WAVEHDR));

    waveOutClose(hWaveOut);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `waveInOpen` should be opened with `CALLBACK_EVENT`, or `CALLBACK_THREAD` etc. I don't know what `WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT` does by itself. The call back function or thread allow writing the recording on to disk.

Comment: According to your describation, whether you want to record sound to a .wave file? If so, I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [Writing to a WAV File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ee419050(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Please be a bit more clear. There are many functions in your code. One can only assume you are asking about how to write a .wav file.